# elasticsearch node.js delete all docs of an index

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, dml, elasticsearch-query

I’m trying to delete all documents from an index without delete the index itself via node.js API.

I’m trying with deleteByQuery but how can I specify all the docs inside the index?

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @opster.... I was searching for a pure node.js solution and finally I found it.
I want to post it cause I've never seen this code snippet out there on the web.

_

**On client using axios:**

```
     axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/empty_index',
     }).then();
```

_

**On server my express route**

```
     app.post( '/empty_index', function( req, res, next ) {

        const client = new Client({
            node: 'http://localhost:'+process.env.ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
        });

        client.deleteByQuery({
            index: <your-index-name>,            
            body: {
                query: {
                    match_all: {}
                }
            }
        }, function (error, response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
        return res.status( 200 ).send();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the REST API to delete all the docs from your index, for that you need not use the node.js API and you can directly hit below API. [More info on delete all docs examples and different options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-api-example)

### Delete all documents from an index

```
POST <your-index-name>/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {} --> this matches all docs in index, hence deletes all of them.
  }
}
```

**Curl format for as its a POST request, so it's difficult to use it with rest-client**

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/<your-index-name>/_delete_by_query" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
'
```

Comment: many thx... I've already seen this syntax but I'm not sure to understand it. I have to perform a POST request to the url you mentioned?

Comment: yes, and you need to replace <your-index-name> with your index name and before that you need to pass your es-server IP and port

Comment: My express server in on 8080 port. in client-side I'm using axios to make request. I'm trying to perform a POST with url: '127.0.0.1:8080/<my-index-name>/_delete_by_query { "query": { "match_all": {} } }'. But browser says "DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL".

Comment: 8080 is your application port, you elasticsearch must be running on `9200` port if you have not changed its default port

Comment: yes sorry
url: '127.0.0.1:9200/<my-index-name>/_delete_by_query{"query":{"match_all":{}}}',
same error

Comment: can you share the screen-shot of how you are sending this query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211008/discussion-between-marco-allori-and-opster-elasticsearch-ninja).